# Jboss не стартует

Tags: java, jboss

Сервер упал и теперь Jboss не стартует. В чем может быть причина?

```
12:03:08,005 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./-web: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in s$n in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./-web: JBAS018040: Failed to start context

    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:94)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
```

Answer (score 0):

Если не стартует контекст, то надо почистить домен (work), по удалять временные файлы (temp), и если не поможет передеплоить и/или переустановить сервер.

Эта проблема возникает при неправильной настройке.  Если вы столкнулись с проблемой после изменения конфигурации, попробуйте проверить измененную конфигурацию.